# Replacing main OS in multiboot system with Windows and other Linux distros?

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, windows

I have Windows XP, Windows 7, and several Linux distros installed on different partitions. I would like to replace my main Linux installation (an earlier version of Ubuntu) with a newer one. This installation manages the boot menu (Grub2) for the other systems.

How do I do that without losing the ability to boot into Windows and other operating systems?

The GRUB does need to be replaced with a newer version... I am trying to figure out how to do that without destroying my computer.

Answer (score 0):

Just install the newer version of Ubuntu and install Grub into the MBR of the first hard drive. This is the default behavior.

If there is a problem, let us know or use boot repair

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair